# Managing a subset of the database in a SQL Server 2008 DB Project

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, database-project

I'm new to using SQL Server 2008 DB Project's in VS 2010.  I found a good [intro](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/05/02/vs-2010-database-project-using-an-existing-database.aspx) to setting them up.  It's nice how they create Tables, Stored Proc's etc as objects.  But is it also a limitation?

I want to use this project to manage 1 stored procedure (for learning).  I do not want to import the entire database because 90% of the database is stuff we do not manage.

I created a new project without doing the import process.  I then added a new stored procedure.  Now I am having difficulty getting the thing to build.  I'm getting various errors saying that I have unresolved references to objects.

How can I add a new stored procedure..build it and deploy it to the database?  Is it possible with this kind of SQL project or do I need to drop back to the old, simple type of SQL projects that VS 2008  and below used?

**Update**
According to another [post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/04/19/requiem-to-the-vs-2003-2005-2008-database-project.aspx), support for the Database Project type is gone.  Support for my situation appears to have been erased.

**UPDATE 2 3/21/2012**
I installed [MSSCCI](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6) which allows me to use SSMS directly with TFS 2010. I no longer needed and found the setup process to be unmanageable for a large database SQL 2008 project.  Especially when you only manage a small % of the DB.

Comment: The link you posted is about the old-style database projects, not the ones you're talking about.

Comment: @John Saunders - I am referring to both types.  The old type supported single item management.  The new project type requires the whole database.  That is the point of my question.

Comment: My point is that it's only the old type that is gone. The new type is alive and well, but does need to know about the things being referenced by your stored procedure. Not necessarily the entire database, but the subset the stored procedure is referencing, and all that they reference, etc.

Comment: @John Saunders - I see what you are saying.  That's still not going to work for me.  That's too long a spaghetti noodle to unravel.  I only want to manage a very small percentage of the database, stored proc's and a handful of tables.  But, their dependencies are constantly growing.  Having to import an unknown # of objects each time you need to add a dependency is way too much overhead in my situation.

Comment: These projects are meant for the case you're trying to use them for. They mean to represent the complete database, even if you're not maintaining all of it. Look up "partial projects" in the MSDN documentation to see how you can import the entire database, but only maintain part of it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I'm not sure I follow you.  The partial projects I read about on MSDN are referring to managing a subset of a database project from a parent database project.  Unless I missed something, there's still a need for a whole database project which is what I need to avoid.

Comment: There is still a full database project, but it can then be ignored, and only the partial projects can be worked on. Note that database projects don't deploy scripts - they build a model of the database schema, then deploy "change scripts" based on the model. If they don't know all of the database objects, then they can't produce the change scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [Partition a Database Project by Using Partial Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193248.aspx). This allows the database project to know the entire schema of the database, at the same time, you need not maintain the entire schema. You can work with the subset of the database that's under active development, for instance (or the subset which is your responsibility), yet the project knows the entire schema. This permits it to create change scripts at deployment time, by comparing the schema in the project with the schema in the target database.

Comment: does this partial projects deal work at all with schema compares? I keep getting all the things missing from either when I do a compare, instead of the stuff relevant minus stuff already referenced via db reference.

Comment: I really don't recall, and I have no current example to check. I would expect that if you did the compare on the "master" project, that it would work. The entire idea is to have the project understand the complete schema. Otherwise, how could deployment work?

Answer (score 1):

You must import all schema objects referenced by your new stored procedure. But this can become a large task because every referenced object need all it's references too.
More trouble with linked server objects.